# Are there simple command line tools to decode a SQL Injection request string?

Tags: sql

My web server periodically comes under attack, and I get a bunch of requests that look like

/my.page?union+all+select+0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536%2C0x31303235343830303536--

Are there simple command line tools to decode this?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600954/site-has-been-hacked-via-sql-injection

Comment: @GregAskew: That question is asking what happened as a result of an attack.  I'm looking for a tool to help me decode the various results.

Comment: It's too bad a site like: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions doesn't exist yet. :)

Comment: @chris: the top answer has the breakdown

Answer (score 1):

it appears to be the [Havij](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/The+Havij+SQL+Injection+Tool/11011) SQL injection tool. The requests are trying to locate how many columns are in a particular table.

Please learn about preventing SQL injections and attacks like this won't even work.

Comment: I'm aware of Havij, and am very familiar with sql injection.  But I can't find a simple tool to decode what ends up in the log.

Comment: It's just hex. There's many tools online. The hex in question is just random characters (in hex) in order to get a column count.

Comment: Sure, but there are hundreds of request that use different techniques for obfuscating the actual request - I was hoping to be able to extract them from my logs, pipe them to a tool, and view the results.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that does this...what you're asking is for a tool that can detect every possible request and decode them, which i don't believe is possible. You can use something like GreenSQL as a "proxy" to log and report malicious-like queries, but that's all I have.